# Does kotlin coroutines have async call with timer?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

Does Kotlin has possibility to call function async() in coroutines with some time, witch will return default result after time completion?

I found that it's possible to only call await, and than infinity wait the result.

```
async {
        ...
        val result = computation.await()
        ...
}
```

But real production case than you need to return either default result or exception. What is proper way to do something in Kotlin coroutines? Like something similar to this:

```
async {
        ...
        val timeout = 100500
        val result: SomeDeferredClass = computation.await(timeout)
        if (result.isTimeout()) {
           // get default value
        } else {
           // process result
        }
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `withTimeout`-function. It will throw a `CancellationException` when it times out. You could catch this exception and return your default value.

Something like this:

```
async {
    ...
    val timeout = 100500L

    try {
        withTimeout(timeout) {
            computation.await()
        }
        ...
    } catch (ex: CancellationException) {
        defaultValue
    }
}
```

You could also use the `withTimeoutOrNull`-function, which returns `null` on timeout. Like this:

```
async {
    ...
    val timeout = 100500L
    withTimeoutOrNull(timeout) { computation.await() } ?: defaultValue
}
```

This approach won't let you differentiate between a timeout and a computation that returns null though. The default value would be returned in both cases.

For more info, see here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#timeout

Comment: If the timeout passes why does the `computation` get cancelled? I was trying something like this with `CompletableFuture`s so I could add a timer to that future and if it time's out I would either wait again or do something else. But when I tried to wait again it was already completed exceptionally.

Comment: @chriptus13 If you need that behaviour, I think you need to keep your timing logic separate from your computation logic. You could then react on the timer-coroutine, and possibly cancel the computation-coroutine if want that conditionally.

Answer (score 5):

Combining both [Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) and @marstran solution I came to a solution that may fit better to your requirements of having the `await` function with timeout and default value. Also I think it's a cleaner solution

Just define the extension function:

```
suspend fun <T> Deferred<T>.await(timeout : Long, defaultValue : T) =
    withTimeoutOrNull(timeout) { await() } ?: defaultValue
```

And you can use it anywhere. Instead of

```
async {
    ...
    val timeout = 100500L
    withTimeoutOrNull(timeout) { computation.await() } ?: defaultValue
}
```

You can do simply

```
async {
    val timeout = 100500L
    computation.await(timeout, defaultValue)
}
```